# ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Tags: sql

Given a staff table with the following attributes:

> ec,name,code,dob,salary

List the staff members earning more than the average salary.

My solution:

```
select* from staff where salary > avg(salary);
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

An aggregate may not appear in the `WHERE` clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a `HAVING` clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Example using `WHERE` clause :

```
select *
from staff 
where salary > (select avg(salary) from staff)
```

Example using `HAVING` clause :

```
select deptid,COUNT(*) as TotalCount
from staff
group by deptid
having count(*) > 2
```

`Having` clause specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate. `HAVING` can be used only with the `SELECT` statement. `HAVING` is typically used in a `GROUP BY` clause. When `GROUP BY` is not used, `HAVING` behaves like a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: why is it so? why can count(*)  be used in where clause?

Comment: @jaig: You cannot use `count(*)` in where clause. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: another doubt... why cant i do the following : select* from staff having salary > avg( salary)   but i can do the following: select* from staff having salary > 200

Comment: @jaig: Because, it acts as a simple where clause. See the last part in my edited answer. Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: You can use `where` with `group by`. This an example query that I just ran: `SELECT Team, Count(*) FROM SALARY WHERE SICKLEAVE > 30 GROUP BY Team;`

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman: Ofcourse you can use where and group by in the same query. The question is about using aggregation function **in** where clause. eg: you cannot query `SELECT * FROM SALARY WHERE count(SICKLEAVE) > 30 ;`

Comment: From [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html): "*In the `WHERE` expression, you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (group) functions.*"