# MySQL error with WHERE clause and GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, where-clause, logical-operators

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUbgq.png)

I'm trying to write a query that retrieves the names of all salespeople that have more than $1300 in orders from the tables above. (each salesperson only has one ID.)

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT name, sum(amount)

FROM salesperson

JOIN orders

ON salesperson.ID = orders.salesperson_id

WHERE sum(amount) > 1300 

GROUP BY name;
```

However, it displays the error: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function.

When I remove where clause, it works fine and returns following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwJgy.png)

Which is pretty similar to what I want except that there's no filter for sum(amount) less than 1300.

What did I do wrong with where clause and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please read about [`HAVING`](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/having) (post-aggregation filtering).

Comment: no where... `HAVING sum(amount)>1300` after  GROUP BY.  The issue is order of operation.  The where clause executes before the select; so the sum hasn't been determined yet.  the having clause executes after the select; which means the sum is known and can be used as a filter.

Comment: If you start using a site like sqlfiddle.com to post these questions it becomes really easy for us to help you.  It would  also be a very good  tool for you as I presume a newcomer to sql .  Please don't ever paste text ( eg console output) in screenshots on this site.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Aggregate can not appear in the `WHERE` clause, but you can use `HAVING` in the following way:

```
SELECT name, sum(amount)

FROM salesperson

JOIN orders

ON salesperson.ID = orders.salesperson_id

GROUP BY name

Having sum(amount) > 1300;
```

Comment: You can also reference this Stack Overflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171977/error-1111-hy000-invalid-use-of-group-function)

Comment: Thank you for help Ryan. The online course I took didn't cover about 'HAVING' so I didn't know about it. Now I know it because of your help. Thanks!