# Laravel eloquent whereHas where first date is after a specific date

Tags: laravel

I have two related tables:

`publications`:

```
| id | name    |
| 1  | Test    |
| 2  | Example |
```

`publication_dates`:

```
| id | publication_id | date       |
| 1  | 1              | 2020-02-01 |
| 2  | 1              | 2020-02-10 |
| 3  | 1              | 2020-01-25 |
| 4  | 2              | 2020-01-10 |
| 5  | 2              | 2019-12-15 |
```

Now for example I would like to get all `publications` where the first date of `publication_dates` is after `2020-01-01`. So I tried the following:

```
$publications = Publication::whereHas('dates', function($query) {
   $query->whereRaw("MIN(date) > '2020-01-10'");
});
```

But this returns the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

which revers to `MIN(date)`. So my question remains how can I get all publications with the first date being after `2020-01-01` or any other specific date. From the example above I would expect to get the publication with id `1` since the first date of `2` is `2019-12-15`

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171977/error-1111-hy000-invalid-use-of-group-function

Comment: @Avi using havingRaw returns the following: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'publication_dates.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` which might be caused by a with method used earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reverse querying logic and then you can use [relationship absence](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$date = Carbon::create('2020-01-10');
$publications = Publication::whereDoesntHave('dates', function(Builder $query) use ($date) {
    $query->where('date', '<', $date->toDateString());
});
```

You can also go further and make [local scope method for query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes) in model

```
// Publication model


/**
 * Scope a query to only include publications that has date newer than $date
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @param string|object Carbon $date
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeDatesNewerThan($query, Carbon $date)
{
    return $query->whereDoesntHave('dates', function(Builder $query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('date', '<', $date->toDateString());// or set '<=' if more appropriate
    });
}
```

Then somewhere in code i.e. newer than last 30 days

```
// $publications = Publication::datesNewerThan(Carbon::now()->subDays(30))->get();
```

Comment: Haven't thought of this approach but it works with just 1 query. Maybe have to make a new question about this. But I was wondering how it would work for a exact first date, would that mean to use the answer of Shobi but than make it equals to?

Comment: @SuperDJ New question would be appropriate because I have answered exactly to what was stated in question "where first date is after a specific date" <= **after** specific date.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the error is because you are using an aggregate function without a proper group by clause, You could use a join to tackle this. but here is a slightly different approach using the [subquery join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins).

```
$firstDates = PublicationDate::groupBy('publication_id')
->selectRaw('publication_id, MIN(date) as first_date'); // assuming you have a model called PublicationDate for the publication_dates table

Publication::joinSub($firstDates, 'first_dates', function($join){
    $join->on('first_dates.publication_id', '=', 'publications.id')
         ->where('first_date', '>','2020-01-10');
})->get();
```