# Ages of people above average MySQL ages WHERE, HAVING How?

Tags: mysql

Question: Show which people are alive, their ages to people above the average age of living people.

```
SELECT nome, TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, data_nasc,CURDATE()) AS "Idade"
FROM pessoas
WHERE data_morte IS NULL AND TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, data_nasc,CURDATE()) > AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, data_nasc,CURDATE()));
```

When I put it in Mysql, this error appears, I've tried in several ways and I couldn't solve it, can you help me please?
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: I put it the correct way, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171977/error-1111-hy000-invalid-use-of-group-function)

Comment: You can't use aggregate functions in the `WHERE` clause. Use `HAVING` instead.

Comment: How Could a Use? Could you show me? I don't know "HAVING"

Comment: Why my question is closed? It's different!