# error 1111 (hy000) invalid use of group function when i use count() in group contact

Tags: mysql

```
select
    `lv_ta30`.`states`.`name` AS `states`,
  group_concat(  DISTINCT 
    CONCAT( `lv_ta30`.`user_groups`.`name` ,' ,',count(`lv_ta30`.`user_groups`.`name`)) 
    
   separator ' ; ') 
from
    (`lv_ta30`.`user_groups`
left join (`lv_ta30`.`user_group_affiliations`
left join (`lv_ta30`.`users`
left join `lv_ta30`.`states` on
    ((`lv_ta30`.`states`.`id` = `lv_ta30`.`users`.`state_id`))) on
    ((`lv_ta30`.`user_group_affiliations`.`user_id` = `lv_ta30`.`users`.`id`))) on
    ((`lv_ta30`.`user_group_affiliations`.`user_group_id` = `lv_ta30`.`user_groups`.`id`)))
where
    ((`lv_ta30`.`user_groups`.`id` in (3, 33, 34, 70, 1, 39, 87, 88))
        and (`lv_ta30`.`user_group_affiliations`.`active` = 1)
            and (`lv_ta30`.`user_group_affiliations`.`end_date` > now())
                and isnull(`lv_ta30`.`user_group_affiliations`.`deleted_at`))
group BY 
    `states`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171977/error-1111-hy000-invalid-use-of-group-function)